# How to clear js/css files from chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, caching

I have checked the disable cache in chrome console, yet js and css files are not refreshed, I have tried clearing cache and history manually but still nothing, it is not server-side either because from another browser the files are the latest...

Comment: Cntrl f5 for a force refresh

Answer (score 2):

#### You can do it in two ways:

1. **Hard Refresh**

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.
2. **Incognito Mode**

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to start a Private Browsing Session.
3. **Clear History**

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to clear your history.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or use this plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache-shortcut/jnajhcakejgchhbjlchkfmdidgjefleg

Answer (score 1):

Hit Cntrl+F5 and hit Return...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know you said it isn't server side, but it really can be.
Try to put version on your script/style as my example:

```
<link href="../Styles/style1.css?v=1.2.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js?v=1.2.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
```